# constrained portfolio optimization in matlab

Tags: optimization, portfolio-optimization, matlab

I am working through this paper, http://www.nber.org/papers/w8922.pdf

I want to implement the portfolio weight constraints see page 6-7.

Here is the brief overview of my problem:

Let `w` be the set of weights representing a portfolio. Then, mean-variance problem is to find the portfolio weights that minimizes portfolio variance, `argmin w'Sw` 
subject to `w'I = 1` which represents weights sum up to 1 and S is the estimated covariance matrix.

In this framework, portfolio weights are constrained by lower and upper bounds such as:

[image]

[image]

Then, the authors show that the following proposition is for the symmetric and positive semi-definite covariance matrix for the minimum global variance portfolios:

[image]

Here new covariance matrix is the shrunk version of S. I am trying to implement this in Matlab. My question is therefore, is there a method to implement a constrained optimization such as this or any suggestions as to how I could go about doing this?

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try fmincon for solving (1)-(4).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try it. Does it solve for when S in singular matrix.

Comment: fmincon does not rely on matrix decomposition, so it shouldn't be a problem.